# Mime type for rss file generated by php?

Tags: .htaccess, rss

I use php to auto generate an rss file from a database by putting some php commands in the rss file then changing the htaccess file in the rss directory so that the xml file will be parsed for php like this

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .xml
```

But when i go to validate my feed it says the feed is valid but is being sent as a text file and I should change the htacces to include `AddType application/xml`. But when I add that after the php line, then the file won't execute the php commands in the file

What's the best solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
header('Content-Type: application/rss+xml;charset= utf-8 ');
```

Comment: and ISO-8859-1 for what reason?

Comment: @NullPointer i know what ISO-8859-* is, but the asker didn't specify he wants ISO-8859-1. Maybe he uses UTF without knowing it, and this line will then break the encoding in his RSS page.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I use utf-8, so this is fine

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the Content-Type in your PHP code. Add this for example to your PHP code :

```
header('Content-Type: application/rss+xml');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
header('Content-Type: application/rss+xml');
```

to your code. Also I'd suggest to **write** your XML instead of generating it on the fily. I pretty much doubt it changes so frequently.

Answer (score 0):

You should add at the top of the file:

```
header('Content-type: application/atom+xml');
```

before send any content